# SQL Select on MVC4 Controller

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, select, controller

I am trying to perform a SELECT on the M1lhao table of Sorteio entity (database).

I don't want to go the traditional "string query" or AddWithParameter() way, i wanted to use the MVC4 EF5 available methods.

The following code passes the entire Table to the View, that i can do a foreach in the View and all works fine. What i am looking for is how can i do a SQL query, so i can pass only the element(s) i want, sorted DESCending (for example), obviously on a List and obeying the Model that the View expects.

Essentially i want a replacement for (i tried variants too, db.Milhao, etc):

```
var data = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT * From M1lhao WHERE DrawID = {0}", id);
```

The problem with Find() is that it only searches primary keys.

The complete code:

```
public class M1lhaoController : Controller
{
    private Sorteio db = new Sorteio();

    public ActionResult Index(int id = 1)
    {
        var data = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT * From M1lhao WHERE DrawID = {0}", id); // the variable data comes as -1
        M1lhao m1lhao = db.M1lhao.Find(id);
        if (m1lhao == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(db.M1lhao.ToList());
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try as shown below.

```
var data = db.M1lhao.Where(m=>m.DrawID == id).Select(p=>p);
```

You can learn more about [**Method-Based Query Syntax : Projection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896275(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That seems exactly the direction i was expecting. Can you just elaborate a little further, more precisely how can i configure my SQL Query.

Comment: please see the update.if you need more please let me know.

Comment: I was able to make it work now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're warmly welcome :) Hope you'll `accept the answer` too :)